# Transfering ssl certificate issued by a Windows Domain Controller CA to another machine running IIS

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, windows-server-2019, windows-server-core, iis-10

I have two AD servers in a domain, both running Windows Server 2019, the second is a Core server configured as a RODC.
I have the main server working as a Certification Authority, where I'm supposed to issue the certificates for the internal websites that are running on the Core server.
I need to enable SSL on the websites that are running on the Core server, but using the certificates generated on the main server, so far I haven't found a way to do that.
The closest I got was through the "Certificates" MMC snap-in, but when I try to import the .pfx file I get the notification that importing a .pfx file to a remote certificate store is not supported.
How can I assign these certificates, that are issued and located in the main server, to the websites running on IIS in the Core server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the PFX on Server Core installation using `certutil.exe` command-line tool:

```
certutil -importPFX c:\mypfxx.pfx
```

provide a password for PFX when prompted. Then you can connect remotely to IIS server using IIS Management Console and create HTTPS binding for website.

Comment: I guess I won't be able to use a nice GUI to do that, but at least I got it working with that, thanks.

Comment: that's correct, you cannot use GUI on server core and cannot use remote Certificate managers to install the certificate remotely, CLI is your the only choice.